# spl_autoload_register que hace exactamente?

Tags: php

estoy siguiendo un curso y no me queda completamente claro esta funcion, a lo que entiendo es que no necesito llamar por ejemplo a un archivo de funciones con un require ya que automaticamente lo buscara si no lo encuentra, no se si estoy en lo correcto pero quisiera comprenderlo mejor.
Gracias!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola un gusto en saludarte.

Basicamente esa funcion hace es incluir cada archivo que tengas en determinada ruta que le asignes:

por ejemplo tienes 20 archivos base para tu proyecto para no hacer

include 1 ... 
include 2...
etc
etc

Usas esa funcion:

te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
            $filename = strtolower($class_name) . '.php';
            $file = '/ruta/' . $filename;
            if (file_exists($file) == false) {
                return false;
            }
            include ($file);
        });
```

Lo que hace es que toma cada archivo de la carpeta ruta y lo incluye en el proyecto. como nota cada archivo, su nombre debe ser igual a la clase que lo contiene.

Si tienes un archivo usuario.php dentro la clase tambien se debe llamar class usuario {}.

Es muy util en proyectos muy grandes, y tambien es usado por composer para incluir librerias.

puedes ver mas ejemplos en:

[spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Saludos...